# Disable Aero zoom effect on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, aero, appearance

I'm used to the perceived speed-boost in XP by disabling window animation, and although it is nicer in Vista, it's still a noticeable and pointless lag for the window to be displayed.  The same options don't seem to exist in the Appearance Settings, the Effects menu in the control panel;

Is there a way to disable window fade/zoom when clicking on an application in the taskbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're still there, but like much of the settings, have had one of their modes of access disabled. You can still get to them by going to Control Panel\System, clicking on Advanced System Properties, and on the Advanced tab clicking Settings... under Performance. The first tab, Visual Effects, contains the options you want.

P.S. Thanks for asking this question, it reminded me that I need to mess with those settings myself for my new computer.

Comment: Lovely, not where I would have wanted to look (given GP security over system configuration) but works very well on a PC you control, thanks.